# Local parameter of $L(s,f)$ at infinity $k_j$

Tags: analytic-number-theory, zeta-functions, l-functions

one of the criteria for $L(s,f)$ to be an $L$-function is if it has a Gamma factor

$\gamma(f,s)=\pi^{-ds/2} \prod_{j=1}^d \Gamma\left(\frac{s+k_j}{2}\right)$
where d is the degree of the Euler product.
However, I do not understand how one determines the value of $k_j$.

For instance, for the Dedekind zeta function, we have
$\gamma(f,s)=\pi^{-ds/2} \Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)^{r_1+r_2} \Gamma\left(\frac{s+1}{2}\right)^{r_2}$
where $r_1$ is the number of real embeddings of the field K and $r_2$ the number of pairs of complex embeddings such that $d=r_1+2r_2$.

I do not understand why $k_j= 0$ or $1$.

Thanks

Comment: I dont see what you mean. The known L-functions are (sometimes conjecturally) in the [Selberg class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selberg_class). The Gamma factor is  $Q^s \prod_{j=1}^d \Gamma(\omega_j s+k_j)$ with $Q >0,\omega > 0, \Re(k_j) \ge 0$ and $d$ finite

Comment: Did you follow a proof of the functional equation for $\zeta_K(s)$, which one ?

Comment: These definitions were used in the book  "Analytic Number Theory "
Henryk Iwaniec and Emmanuel Kowalski on pages 94(definition of the gamma factor) and  p.125 (Dedekind zeta function)

Comment: What he says is that the L-functions in this book all have a Gamma factor of this form. But due to the formulas for [the Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General), you'll often have $\Gamma(s)2^{1-s}\sqrt{\pi}$ instead of $\Gamma(s/2)\Gamma((s+1)/2)$